# Create Non-blocking AND Interactive animation in Open3D

Tags: python, mesh, open3d

I am working on an Open3D project and I am trying to figure out a way to perform non-blocking animation and interactivity at the same time. Essentially, as each frame is drawn, I want to be able to rotate the camera.

```
vis_voxel = o3d.visualization.Visualizer()
sphere=o3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.create_sphere()
sphere.compute_vertex_normals)
\\
vis_voxel.create_window(window_name="Vis Voxel", width=1500, height=1000, left=0, top=0)
vis_voxel.add_geometry(sphere)
vis_voxel.poll_events()
while (input("Continue? (Hit enter for yes, type anything for no)")==""):
     sphere.translate([1,1,1])
     vis_voxel.update_geometry(sphere)
     vix_voxel.poll_events()
     vix_voxel.update_renderer()
```

In essence, I want to be able to rotate the camera and freely interact with the sphere, but on command, advance the animation and then freely interact again. Is there a way to do this?